# Firebug breakpoints in dynamically generated jQuery?

Tags: jquery, debugging, firebug

So Firefox+Firebug seems to be the tool of choice for debugging jQuery. Its certainly very handy.

I can get breakpoints in JavaScript code that was there when the page originally loaded (the breakpoint-able lines show up with green line numbers in Firebug).

But when jQuery code gets returned by an Ajax call, I can't get breakpoints to attach to it. Is this even possible?

For example when the result of an Ajax call is a load of html that I plug into a DIV, and that html also includes some jQuery code to attach a new click handler to a button ... How do I get a breakpoint in the click handler?

(NB: It took me a while to find where the JavaScript that gets returned from Ajax calls shows up - in the toolbar of the FireBug Script tab, you have to click on the second dropdown to show a list of JavaScript snippets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is not possible, cause ajax code is not inserted from a file.

What you can do though is to manualy insert a `debugger;` statement into the js code when receiving the ajax result.

Comment: You mean get the server to add `debugger;` statements? Thanks.

Comment: you can do that or you insert them onSuccess in after the request has been received

Comment: Ah right, I see. Is the general principle with FireBug that javascript thats in a file can be debugged? If so, I could move most of my jQuery functions into a pre-prepared file and only add the event handlers dynamically. Would that then let me place breakpoints in the pre-prepared stuff?

Comment: hmm, i am not that sure - but you should give it a try :)

Answer (score 1):

You can add a breakpoint to an AJAX network request using the Firebug network panel using the button "break on XHR" on the upper left corner or adding the breakpoint on the left side of an already executed network request.
There is also an official Firebug breakpoint demo page: https://getfirebug.com/doc/breakpoints/demo.html#net